# Symmetric linear transformation has symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

I want show that

> Let $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a symmetric linear transformation, i.e. $T(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} \cdot T(\mathbf{y})$ for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb R^n$. If $B$ is any orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$, then the matrix $[T]_B$ is symmetric.

Why is this only true for an orthonormal basis? I tried to prove it and showed it for any basis and so I must have made a mistake. Where has it gone wrong? I found those two questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991509/symmetric-matrix-if-symmetric-linear-transformation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300644/show-that-the-matrix-is-a-symmetric-matrix) but they didn't explain that.

---

Let $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $\Bbb R^n$. We know that $[T]_B [\mathbf{x}]_B \cdot [\mathbf{y}]_B = [\mathbf{x}]_B \cdot [T]_B [\mathbf{y}]_B$ is true for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb R^n$. So it must especially be true for all $\mathbf{v}_i$ which means $[T]_B [\mathbf{v}_i]_B \cdot [\mathbf{v}_j]_B = [\mathbf{v}_i]_B \cdot [T]_B [\mathbf{v}_j]_B$ for every $1 \le i,j \le n$. Now $[\mathbf{v}_j]_B$ has a $1$ in the $i$-th slot and zeros everywhere else. Therefore for the LHS we get from the matrix multiplication of $[T]_B [\mathbf{v}_i]_B$ the $i$-th row of $[T]_B$ and the scalar product with $[\mathbf{v}_j]_B$ gives the $j$-th entry from this $i$-th row. Analogously for the RHS. Thus we get $\left([T]_B\right)_{ji}=\left([T]_B \right)_{ij}$ which means $[T]_B = [T]_B^T$ and so $[T]_B$ is symmetric.

Comment: The point that fails for a non-orthonormal basis is "and the scalar product with [vj]B gives the j-th entry from this i-th row."

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks. Can you clarify why? If my scalar product is the standard scalar product, and I have $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & \ldots & a_n \end{bmatrix}^T \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0 & \ldots & 1 & \ldots & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ where the $1$ is in the $j$-th slot, then I get $a_j$, right? So why wouldn't the above give me the $j$-th entry from the $i$-th row? The scalar product is the standard scalar product regardless of the basis, no?

Comment: The formula for the scalar product in terms of coordinates depends on the basis these coordinates refer to. For a simplest example take "standard" dot product and take the basis $B=\{(2,0),(0,2)\}$ of $R^2$. Now take the vector $v=(1,0)$ (in the standard basis). Its  coordinates in $B$ are $(1/2,0)$, but it doesn't mean $v\cdot v=1/4$. More abstractly, there is a change-of-basis involved, as there is for matrices of linear transformations.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks, I get it!